# Locate a user's bashrc file

Tags: users, postgresql

Really confused.

Upon running

```
cat etc/passwd
```

I have found this:

```
postgres:x:117:126:PostgreSQL administrator,,,:/var/lib/postgresql:/bin/bash
```

meaning I have a postgres user, right?

I want to change the bashrc environment file of this user to make commands available to it.

```
 /var/lib/postgresql
```

doesn't contain a bashrc file, and

```
/bin/bash
```

doesn't contain it either, so I don't really know what's going on. All I know is a created postgres using the

```
useradd
```

command, so why do I have some weird user with no home directory? So confused :(

Answer (score 1):

The `.bashrc` file contains commands to be run when `bash` starts for this user (normally when he logs in). So you need to `su - postgresql` that this file is executed.

If that file does not exist you can simpy create it and fill it with whatever you want to be executed when the user starts a new bash.

But take care the `postgresql` user is not meant to be a normal system user that executes a bash. It's a user just for the daemon `postgresql`.

Comment: Where do I create the .bashrc ?

Comment: @Starkers daemon users are a little different than shell users, `.bashrc` runs when a login shell for the user is used, and bash opens, like when a user opens the terminal.  postgresql isn't designed to be that kind of a user, and it may not actually run a `.bashrc`...

Comment: The home directory is `/var/lib/postgresql` and there you can create a file called `.bashrc`. The owner of the file must be `postgresql`. But, as Thomas W. said, this will execute when this user opens a shell, not when you start the daemon...